# Interactive shell in PHPstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is it possible to use [Interactive shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) in PHPstorm like PyCharm?

Comment: Since there's a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12069) for this, I think it's not in available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a PHP REPL you can use the Xdebug interactive shell. To do this, you need to run the php script in debug mode, setting a breakpoint, and this can be done directly from Phpstorm, without using a browser (see [CLI Script debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-a-php-cli-script.html))

[image]

To run it, you don’t need to configure xdebug on the server - the main thing is to connect it to the interpreter of your project by filling out the "Debugger extension" field (what to fill in - [see here](https://xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php), points 2 and 4). The interpreter itself must be selected in the debug configuration or set to default for the project

[image]

If your interpreter is remote, and connected via SSH, and the Xdebug 9000/9003 ports are not closed on the server, then you do not need to create an SSH tunnel

Xdebug REPL also has features that allow you to execute code directly from the editor without copying it to the console:

1. Quick Evaluate Expression (Ctrl+Alt+F8, or Alt+Shift+mouseClick):
   [image]
2. Evaluate Expression window (Alt+F8, but you can also assign mouse shortcut):
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, Isn't it possible to use it without a php file? I mean open the console and go.

Answer (score 5):

No, but there's a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12069) for it you can track.

Comment: The original feature request (which got implemented in the latest EAP  released 2 weeks ago) is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5370 .

Answer (score 2):

The [feature request mentioned by @Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431022) is now [closed as rejected,](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-12069) but there is also [a feature request that is a continuation of it, and describes why it should be implemented](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-68748/Support-Php-console-REPL-integration) (it is in the "collecting feedback" stage and you can vote for it). Currently, as a temporary option, you can use the xdebug console, [as described by @ax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/16343464).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "above". Note that display order of answers is individually configurable here (for me e.g. your post is top most beneath only the question).  So please refer by link to the post you mean. I think you mean "The one above" to be https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431022/7733418 but I am not sure where "as described above" could be, I do not see a description ...

Answer (score 0):

There is one trick that allows you to “integrate” the php console into Phpstorm and make it a kind of interactive PyCharm shell. To do this, you need to run the console in debug mode. This cannot be done directly, but you can pass the -a parameter in the debugging configuration for a php script, then in debugging mode it will not be the script that will be launched, but the php console.
[image]

[image]

However, overall this console is worse than the [Xdebug REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/22473197):

1. In [Xdebug REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/22473197) you write 1+1 and immediately get 2, but here you need to write echo 1+1.
2. Each time you need to re-include your project with libraries in the console, whereas in [Xdebug REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/22473197) this can be written in the file for which it is launched
3. The history of commands is not remembered
4. [The Quick Evaluate Expression and Evaluate expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/22473197) features are not available.

However, you can run Xdebug even from here, but only if the php version is > 8 and [Xdebug is connected to the interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32506245/22473197). You need to enter `xdebug_break();` in the console, and this will be similar to using debugger; in the javascript console - debugging will begin. P.S It should also be taken into account that this is not an [official method - php < 8 version it was impossible](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1269), and a solution to the problem was not officially announced.
[image]