# Run function php in console phpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm a new php and I'm using phpStorm to develop, there is anyway can run a function in terminal (console) in phpStorm?
For example I can type in terminal (console):

```
> php function.php getProduct();
```

Comment: Use this command Ctrl+Shift+X,more details can be found here 
https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/command-line-tools-console-tool-window.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430996/interactive-shell-in-phpstorm#answer-32506245

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, you can open a shell terminal by going to the Menu Bar, then **View --> Tool Windows --> Terminal**. If you want to start a PHP console inside the terminal window, run `php -a`. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) for more information on the interactive PHP terminal.

**Edit**

It seems that the root cause of this not working is that you're running in a Windows environment and `php.exe` is not in your command PATH. See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath) for instructions on adding `php.exe` to your `PATH`. If you run into problems, there is some additional information in the comments on the linked page. Here are the instructions for Windows 7, XP, Vista, 2008, 2012 and up:

- Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start → Control Panel)
- Go to the Advanced tab
- Click on the 'Environment Variables' button
- Look into the 'System Variables' pane
- Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)
- Double click on the Path entry
- Enter your PHP directory at the end, including ';' before (e.g.
  ;C:\php)
- Press OK

Comment: I know that, but I alway got error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Is this Windows or Mac? And when did you see this error; when you opened Terminal? Or ran php -a?

Comment: Ah, interesting. Are you running php 5.1+?

Comment: *"I alway got error "The system cannot find the file specified""* 1) Make sure that path to your php.exe in listed in `PATH` environment variable 2) If it's listed by PhpStorm still does not see it -- try reboot (or at least logout and login)

Comment: Ah, you need to put the PHP installation directory in your `PATH`. I will add instructions to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to run a function inside a file with syntax like that out of the box. (You could write code which evaluates the arguments passed via the CLI and make it execute that function, but I don't think that's what you're interested in.)

You'll have to write a PHP script which imports and executes the function. You can do that ad-hoc on the command line, e.g.:

```
$ php -r 'require "function.php"; print_r(getProduct());'
```

Or you go into interactive mode and do the same there:

```
$ php -a
php > require 'function.php';
php > print_r(getProduct());
```